# Jquery Appended div CSS class + functionality ignored

Tags: jquery, css

I have a button being clicked, once clicked its changes from condensed to collapsed and vice versa. I first append it to my content region as a normal block, which once clicked expands to become a menu. I then proceed to append the same button to the menu itself and replace the value so it signifies a left-pointed arrow. The button has the class aside-button as a permanent default and toggles between aside-collapsed and aside-condensed appropriately. My problem is that once the button is appended to the li of the menu it ignores the aside-button css and its functionality. Any and all help will be much appreciated. Thank You

THE JQUERY

```
(function ($, Drupal){
  Drupal.behaviors.asideColldense = {
   attach : function() {
        $('<div class=aside-button><p>&#9654;</p></div>').appendTo('#content');
        $('.aside-button').addClass('aside-condensed');
        var aside = $('#block-panels-mini-aside-navigation');
        aside.hide();

        function collapseOrCondense(event) {
          aside.toggle();
          $('.aside-button').toggleClass('aside-collapsed');
          $('.aside-button').toggleClass('aside-condensed');
          if($('.aside-button').hasClass('aside-collapsed')) {
            $('.aside-button p').contents().replaceWith('&#9664;');
            $('.aside-button').appendTo('.aside-menu li.menu-path-hosting');    
          } 
          else{
            $('.aside-menu li.menu-path-hosting .aside-button   p').contents().replaceWith('&#9654;');
            $('.aside-menu li.menu-path-hosting .aside-button').appendTo('#content');
          }
  }
  $('.aside-button').on('click', collapseOrCondense);
 }
}

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

THE CSS

```
  .aside-menu ul.nice-menu li {
      border: .118em solid rgb(90,90,90);
      float: left;
      background: rgb(38,38,38);
    }

   .aside-menu {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     z-index: 10;
     display: inline-block;
   }

   .aside-condensed {
     position: fixed;
     display: inline-block;
     top: 50vmin;
     left: 0%;
     margin: 0;  
     width: 5vmin;
     z-index: 10;
   }

    .aside-collapsed {
      display: inline-block;
      /* float: right; */
      margin: 0;  
     }

     .aside-button p {
       background-color: rgb(38,38,37);
       text-align: center;
       cursor: pointer;
       border: rgb(222,222,222) solid 2px;
       border-left: none;
       padding: 17.5% .5% 17.5% 0;
       margin: 0;
       font-size: 2.5vmin;
       }

       .aside-button p:hover {
         background-color: rgb(222,222,222);
         color: rgb(50,50,41);
         border: rgb(50,50,41) solid 2px;
         border-left: none;
         padding-bottom: 13.5%;
        } 

      .aside-collapsed p {
        border: none;
        font-size: 1.75vw;
       }

      .aside-collapsed p:hover {
        background-color: rgb(38,38,37);
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
        border: none;
        border-left: none;
        padding-bottom: 13.5%; 
        }
```

PICTURE

[image: Condensed, works]

[image: Collapsed button highlighed in yellow, ignores aside-button css and jquery, so it also refuses to close]

Condensed, works

Collapsed button highlighed in yellow, ignores aside-button css and jquery, so it also refuses to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paragraphs width seemed to overlap the button and prevented it from reacting as it should, figured this out by moving the button to the bottom of the page where the p's weren't parallel. Thanks for everyone's time.

Comment: that's my intent though I have to wait 2days before I can mark it as such, instead I used the "fixed" tag as a temporary substitute which would serve the same purpose. But experience talks, so ill listen boss.